# Implementing Marketing Cloud Conversion Tracking - Non transactional

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to track a click from a Marketing Cloud email to a wordpress landing page to fill out a form and when they reach the Thank you/Confirmation page, goal is to send the conversion back to Marketing Cloud.

I have set up the URL to contain Conversion = true

Looking for the next steps.  I found this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_conversion_landingpg.htm&type=5

If this information is passed automatically to the landing page, what do I need to put on the landing page and where (wordpress) to send the information back to Marketing Cloud?

Trying to keep this super simple, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but there's no super simple wordpress plugin for conversion tracking.

Though you tick the 'conversion tracking' option in Marketing Cloud, all that this is doing is adding some parameters (subscriber key etc) to the URL. When the landing page loads, you will need to script something on your landing page to retrieve the parameters and store them somehow (Cookie, Session, or continue to pass on URL).

When the customer performs the actual on your website e.g. submits form, then on the 'conversion page' i.e. the success/thank you page, you need to script something to now retrieve the attributes you stored in the cookie/session.

Once you have retrieved the attributes, you can then fire these back to Marketing Cloud using a Conversion Tracking pixel. Marketing Cloud then knows and Tracks the customers action as a conversion

It's technical to implement - though for a developer it can be simple.

Another option you could look at for tracking the conversion page is to us Predictive Intelligence / Web Analytics. That requires some JavaScript on WordPress but then it will allow you to pass pageviews back to SFMC